# Acces Path.Effect Propertys from Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, opacity, dropshadow

```
<!-- language: c# -->
```

I want to change from code behind the `Opacity` of the path effect `PART_Shadow`.
I tried the `GetTemplateChild` method but it returns only *NULL*.

```
<Path x:Name="PART_Path" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.0" Stroke="#ff1c1c1a">
    <Path.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="PART_Shadow" Color="LightGray" BlurRadius="5" Direction="45"     
          ShadowDepth="3" RenderingBias="Performance"/>
    </Path.Effect>
</Path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I tried to find it too early, in `OnApplyTemplate` is `GetTemplateChild` working.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    var _Shadow = GetTemplateChild("PART_Shadow");
}
```